Unable to execute the printindex command
I want to print the index for my LaTeX notes using the \printindex command. I am using the book class.
I have added the package makeidx and I issue the \makeindex command in my preamble. I even changed the .idx file to .ind and re-ran latex, but I am getting an error which says "Undefined control sequence \indexentry".
Could someone please help me resolve this?

Welcome to TeX.SE!
As mentioned in a prior comment by cfr, to get an index to print via the makeidx package, you must generate the index for your TeX file, via some call to makeindex, after your first call to latex (or similar compilation commands).
You can find a detailed guide to doing so, in Leslie Lamport's original (and still very useful!) 1987 guide to MakeIndex. (You might also find this other index styling Answer helpful.)
Alternatively, I would recommend just using Latexmk, which will issue this command for you, during its complete build process. You can also pass it configuration options for this purpose, if needed.
